# Array is too large

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm on Visual Studio, and I'm building a 64 bit program. I have 16gb RAM. I run into the following error:

```
int main()
{
    auto* p = new char[2'200'000'000]; // array is too large
    auto* p = new char[2'100'000'000]; // This is fine

}
```

This is 2.2 gigabytes I want to allocate. What's wrong here?

Edit: This does compile, it's just Intellisense it seems that gives that message.

Comment: No idea, but if you want to allocate such a large block of memory I suggest that you use the O/S native API rather than C++. On Windows that would be a call to [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc)

Comment: Who says that the "array is too large"?

Comment: @Pete Visual Studio Intellisense says so. But the code (in my VS) does actually compile.

Comment: _'I run into the following error:'_  What does your compiler say?

Comment: From what I've heard, like most Microsoft products, Intellisense is often wrong.

Comment: I suspect the error message you're seeing is a left-over from the 32-bit days, when you were limited to 2 gigabytes (note that 2 gigabytes is 2,147,483,648, so your smaller one is *just* under that limit).

Comment: Have you checked that the destination of your project is indeed 64 bits?

Comment: It is only an intelisense issue. It should compile and run with no issue (assuming the platform you mentioned - x64 with enough memory). If intelisense bothers you, you can "trick" it by using a const variable to store the array size.

Comment: @wohlstad You're right, it does compile. It's an intellisense thing.

Comment: why don't you try to use unsigned int data type  or long ?

Comment: this seems to be fixed in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: There is something 32-bit going on, obviously, considering that 2³¹ is `2'147'483'648`. I can imagine that 2³¹ could well be the largest possible array size for a 32-bit process. Of course this varies from platform to platform based on how the address space is organized; one would get much less than that on an old MIPS on which an entire half of the address space was physically mapped and inaccessible from (not TLB-mapped into) userspace etc.

Comment: Intellisense is *not* the compiler. It's just a tool that *tries* to be helpful - it's often just plain wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please navigate to Tools->Options->C/C++->Intellisense and check if you have ticked`Enable 64-bitIntellisense` .
[image]

In C++, the type of array subscript is `std::size_t`, so the size of the array cannot exceed the size that `size_t` can represent. This data type is declared through typedef in the library file stdio.h.`size_t` is defined as unsigned int on 32-bit systems, which is a 32-bit unsigned integer. It is defined as unsigned long on 64-bit systems, which is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

```
typedef unsigned int size_t；//32-bit
typedef unsigned long size_t;//64-bit
```

It looks like your Intellisense just detects array subscript as int type.(max value :2^31-1=2'147'483'647).

From my understanding, default Intellisense is 32 bit in Visual Studio. When the value is less than or equal to  maximum value of type int(2'147'483'647),the intellisense shows normal. Otherwise, it shows `array is too large`.

AS a workaround, you can also define an unsigned long type variable and then create an array to avoid intellisense error message.
For example
[image]

Hope this can help you.